# Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать так чтобы код js начинался отображаться только тогда, когда секция активная?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullpage

У меня такая ситуация что сайт разбит по секциям с помощью плагина fullPage.js (пример: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ru/#page1 ), то когда я захожу на первую секцию на последний начинается анимация js. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать так чтобы код js начинался отображаться только тогда, когда секция активная?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте коллбэк `onLeave`, как в примере https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/apple.html
или `afterLoad` в примере https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/callbacks.html

Так же каждый активный слайд имеет класс `active`. Анимацию можно привязать к нему.

Comment: Не могу разобраться как использовать afterload?

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался. Благодарю за помощь.